# Xamarin.Forms InvalidProgramException System.InvalidProgramException: Invalid IL code

Tags: c#, mono, xamarin.forms

For my app written using Xamarin.Forms, I use a Result object so I can handle both positive and negative results when querying my server side code:

```
namespace GenerationLondon
{
    public abstract class Result<E, S>
    {
        private Result() {}

        public abstract R fold<R>(Func<E, R> left, Func<S, R> right);

        public abstract void consume (Action<E> left, Action<S> right);

        public static Result<E, S> success(S value)
        {
            return new Success (value);
        }

        public static Result<E, S> error(E value)
        {
            return new Error (value);
        }

        public class Success : Result<E, S>
        {
            private S success;

            public Success(S success)
            {
                this.success = success;
            }

            public override R fold<R> (Func<E, R> left, Func<S, R> right)
            {
                return right.Invoke(success);
            }

            public override void consume (Action<E> left, Action<S> right)
            {
                right.Invoke (success);
            }
        }

        public class Error : Result<E, S>
        {
            private E error;

            public Error(E error)
            {
                this.error = error;
            }

            public override R fold<R> (Func<E, R> left, Func<S, R> right)
            {
                return left.Invoke (error);
            }

            public override void consume (Action<E> left, Action<S> right)
            {
                left.Invoke (error);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

After a user successfully logs in, I fire off 2 requests to the server to gather some information but I keep receiving the following exception:

```
System.InvalidProgramException: Invalid IL code in GenerationLondon.LoginPage/<OnLogin>c__asyncD/<OnLogin>c__AnonStorey14:<>m__1 (System.Collections.Generic.List`1<GenerationLondon.UserEvent>): IL_0008: stfld     0x040000ef


  at GenerationLondon.Result`2+Success[System.String,System.Collections.Generic.List`1[GenerationLondon.UserEvent]].consume (System.Action`1 left, System.Action`1 right) [0x00008] in /Users/tom/Documents/workspace/GenerationLondon/GenerationLondon/Result.cs:39
  at GenerationLondon.LoginPage+<OnLogin>c__asyncD.MoveNext () [0x001df] in /Users/tom/Documents/workspace/GenerationLondon/GenerationLondon/Views/LoginPage.xaml.cs:30
  at --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000b] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/2320/1f068b49/source/maccore/_build/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/git/src/mono/mcs/class/corlib/System.Runtime.ExceptionServices/ExceptionDispatchInfo.cs:61
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.<ThrowAsync>m__0 (System.Object state) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/2320/1f068b49/source/maccore/_build/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/git/src/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/AsyncMethodBuilder.cs:1006
  at UIKit.UIKitSynchronizationContext+<Post>c__AnonStorey0.<>m__0 () [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/2320/1f068b49/source/maccore/src/UIKit/UIKitSynchronizationContext.cs:24
  at Foundation.NSAsyncActionDispatcher.Apply () [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/2320/1f068b49/source/maccore/src/Foundation/NSAction.cs:163
  at at (wrapper managed-to-native) UIKit.UIApplication:UIApplicationMain (int,string[],intptr,intptr)
  at UIKit.UIApplication.Main (System.String[] args, IntPtr principal, IntPtr delegate) [0x00005] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/2320/1f068b49/source/maccore/src/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:77
  at UIKit.UIApplication.Main (System.String[] args, System.String principalClassName, System.String delegateClassName) [0x00038] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/2320/1f068b49/source/maccore/src/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:61
  at GenerationLondon.iOS.Application.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00008] in enter code here/Users/tom/Documents/workspace/GenerationLondon/iOS/Main.cs:17
    enter code here
```

The code in question is as follows:

```
result.consume(async () => {
                Result<string, Details> detailsResult = await restService.getDetails ();
                Result<string, List<Event>> eventsResult = await restService.getEvents();
                eventsResult.consume(async error => await DisplayAlert("Problem communicating with the server", error, "Ok"), events => {
                    detailsResult.consume(async error => await DisplayAlert("Problem communicating with the server", error, "Ok"), details => {
                        loginManager.ShowMainPage (details, events);
                    });
                });
            }, async error => await DisplayAlert("Login Issue", error, "Ok"));
```

The code works fine when run individually, but this exception consistently occurs when trying to process eventsResult after introducing the detailsResult on the iOS simulator. Both calls are returning successfully, and the exception itself is coming from `return right.Invoke(success);` The only thing I can think of is Mono is having issues deriving problems with the types.

Any ideas?

Comment: What's the IL code of the method in question? It might be some subtle bug in the Mono compiler, the code works fine using both .NET's `csc` and Roslyn. There are some warnings that might be causing trouble - for example, your `success` and `error` fields in the derived classes are hiding the static methods in your abstract class (it helps to avoid writing Java in C# :D).

Comment: That would be because I am a Java developer by trait :) The exception provided is all the information that Xcode gave me (incidentally I didn't get any compiler warnings), but will try find the IL code once home